# How to use actionpack (rails) as standalone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use the [actionpack](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack) gem from ruby-on-rails as standalone component with a single file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Metal
    def index
        self.response_body = 'Hello World'
    end
end
```

There are only few examples on such as [rails lightweight stack](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/1942658) which is outdated.

**My question is now how I could bind the `ApplicationController` to a web server with routing capabilities. Similar with `bin/rails server` just without all the bloat.**

Comment: parent class should be: `ActionController::Metal`